# Prove or disprove that for theory $T$, $T \vdash (\phi \rightarrow \psi) \iff T \cup \{\phi\} \vdash \psi$.

Tags: logic, model-theory

Prove or disprove that for theory $T$, $T \vdash (\phi \rightarrow \psi) \iff T \cup \{\phi\} \vdash \psi$.

This seems quite right, but I don't know how to prove it.

So lets start with $\Rightarrow$: So if $\mathcal M \vDash T$ then $\mathcal M \vDash (\phi \rightarrow \psi)$ for every structure  $\mathcal M$. So $\mathcal M \vDash (\lnot \phi \lor \psi)$. How can I continue from here?

Thank you!

Comment: If $\mathcal M \vDash T \cup \{\phi\}$, then $\mathcal M \vDash \phi$, thus
$\mathcal M \not\vDash \neg \phi$ so $\mathcal M \vDash \psi$.

Comment: What does $\lnot (\mathcal M \vDash \lnot \phi)$ actually mean? Does it mean $ \mathcal M \not \vDash \lnot \phi$?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that

Comment: Ehh... I just doesn't see why is the conclusion that $\mathcal M \vDash \psi$

Comment: Because then $\mathcal M \vDash (\neg \phi \vee \psi) \to \psi$ since $\neg\phi$ is false anyway.

Comment: I see now! Great, thank you.

Comment: No problem ;) I'll write this up as an answer so you can accept it and the question is marked as answered.

Comment: But you are "mixing" *derivability* ($\vdash$) with *logical implication* ($\vDash$); in order to do so, you have to specify that for the proof system you are referring to the *Completeness Thoerem* holds (i.e., when you use $\mathcal M \vDash \psi$ to conclude that $T \cup \{ \phi \} \vdash \psi$).

Comment: You've already accepted an answer, but following @MauroALLEGRANZA's comment, you can give a proof of your statement without assuming completeness.

Comment: What type of theory are you talking about?  In particular, what logic is being used? The property in question holds for some logics and not for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathcal M\vDash T\cup \{\phi\}$ then $\mathcal M \vDash \phi$, so $\mathcal M\not\vDash \neg\phi$ (i.e. $\phi$ is false in $\mathcal M$). This implies
$$\mathcal M \vDash (\neg \phi \vee \psi) \to \psi$$
By assumption we can then say $\mathcal M \vDash \psi$ as claimed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you want to talk about structures (or assume completeness, for that matter), so here's a purely syntactic proof.

---

## $T\vdash(\phi\to\psi)\Longrightarrow T\cup\left\{\phi\right\}\vdash\psi$

Let $T\vdash(\phi\to\psi)$.

Then there is a deduction $D=\langle\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_n\rangle$ of $(\phi\to\psi)$ from $T$, where $\gamma_n=(\phi\to\psi)$ and for each $\gamma_k$ ($1\le k\le n$), $\gamma_k$ is either a member of $T$, a logical axiom or obtained by Modus Ponens from two earlier statements $\gamma_i$ and $\gamma_j=(\gamma_i\to\gamma_k)$ (where $i<j<k$).

Thus $D'=\langle\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_n,\phi\rangle$ is a deduction of $\psi$ from $T\cup\left\{\phi\right\}$, where $\phi\in T\cup\left\{\phi\right\}$ and $\psi$ is obtained by Modus Ponens from $(\phi\to\psi)$.

Therefore $T\cup\left\{\phi\right\}\vdash\psi$.

---

## $T\cup\left\{\phi\right\}\vdash\psi\Longrightarrow T\vdash(\phi\to\psi)$

This follows immediately if you assume the Deduction Theorem. But for the sake of completeness, which I am not otherwise assuming (*pun*), here's a proof.

Let $T\cup\left\{\phi\right\}\vdash\psi$.

Then there is a deduction $D=\langle\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_n\rangle$ of $\psi$ from $T\cup\left\{\phi\right\}$. We now work by induction on the length of $D$:

- $n=1$ : then either $\psi\in T$, or $\psi=\phi$, or $\psi$ is a logical axiom (or generalization thereof).

  - $\psi\in T$ : then $T\vdash\psi$. We claim that $\psi\to(\phi\to\psi)$ is a tautology of propositional logic, hence an instance of Axiom $1$. Thus $T\vdash \psi\to(\phi\to\psi)$. By Modus Ponens: $T\vdash\phi\to\psi$.
  - $\psi=\phi$ : by the Law of Identity, $\vdash\alpha\to\alpha$. Thus $T\vdash\phi\to\psi$.
  - $\psi$ is a logical axiom : then $T\vdash\psi$. As above, we can build a tautology and apply Modus Ponens to yield $T\vdash\phi\to\psi$.
- Inductive Hypothesis : assume that for all $k<n$, if $T\cup\left\{\phi\right\}\vdash\gamma_k$ then $T\vdash(\phi\to\gamma_k)$.
- $n>1$ : $\psi=\gamma_n$ must then be obtained by Modus Ponens from two earlier statements $\gamma_i$ and $\gamma_j=(\gamma_i\to\gamma_n)$ (where $i<j<n$). But by IH, since $T\cup\left\{\phi\right\}\vdash\gamma_i$ and $T\cup\left\{\phi\right\}\vdash\gamma_j$, then $T\vdash(\phi\to\gamma_i)$ and $T\vdash(\phi\to\gamma_j)$, the latter being equivalent to $T\vdash(\phi\to(\gamma_i\to\gamma_n))$. Thus by Modus Ponens $T\vdash(\phi\to\psi)$.

Therefore (by the axiom of induction) $T\vdash(\phi\to\psi)$.

---

## $$\therefore T\vdash(\phi\to\psi)\Longleftrightarrow T\cup\left\{\phi\right\}\vdash\psi$$